# how to highlight select text in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

I am new to flutter and I want to make a text highlighter. Something like this.

[image]

I have tried with `SelectableText()`, but it only shows 4 options in `ToolbarOptions` and I can't find something to be able to modify or add new options.

Anyone have any idea what resources I can use to get started?

Thanks in advance.